# Define Changeset for insert query in liquibase

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase, changeset, insert-query

I have two table as following :

```
CREATE TABLE StudentMaster (
  sId      SERIAL,
  StudentName VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE StudentClassMap (
  studnetId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  studentClass VARCHAR(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (studnetId) REFERENCES StudentMaster (sId)
);
```

This is my insert query.

```
INSERT INTO StudentMaster (studentName) values ('Jay Parikh');

INSERT INTO StudentClassMap (studnetId, studentClass)
values ((SELECT sId from StudentMaster where studentName='Jay Parikh'),
        'M.Sc. 1st Year');
```

I want to define **ChangeSet** for thes queries in **`liquibase`**.

For First query **ChangeSet** will be :

```
<changeSet author="unknown" id="insert-example">
    <insert tableName="StudentMaster ">
        <column name="studentName" value="Jay Parikh"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

But I don't know how to define **ChangeSet** for another query.
Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the valueComputed attribute:

```
<changeSet author="unknown" id="insert-example-2">
    <insert tableName="StudentClassMap">
        <column name="studentId" valueComputed="(SELECT sId from StudentMaster where studentName='Jay Parikh')"/>
        <column name="studentClass" value="McSc. 1st Year"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```