# Dropwizard Migrations: create table and insert large data into table using migrations.xml in postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, migration, dropwizard

I need to `create` a `Table` and `insert` the `bulk data` into that `table`.

I have a `MIME-TYPE` `Table` which has number of `mime-types` with `extension`. I need whenever I run `migration step`, the `Table` mime-type should be created with all mime-types on start-up.

Here is the sample of table.

```
Name,Template,Type
1d-interleaved-parityfec,application/1d-interleaved-parityfec,application
3gpdash-qoe-report+xml,application/3gpdash-qoe-report+xml,application
3gpp-ims+xml,application/3gpp-ims+xml,application
activemessage,application/activemessage,application
activemessage,application/activemessage,application
alto-costmap+json,application/alto-costmap+json,application
alto-costmapfilter+json,application/alto-costmapfilter+json,application
alto-directory+json,application/alto-directory+json,application
alto-endpointprop+json,application/alto-endpointprop+json,application
alto-endpointpropparams+json,application/alto-endpointpropparams+json,application
alto-endpointcost+json,application/alto-endpointcost+json,application
alto-endpointcostparams+json,application/alto-endpointcostparams+json,application
alto-error+json,application/alto-error+json,application
```

I have searched and found the [help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356313/define-changeset-for-insert-query-in-liquibase) but I need to `insert` the `bulk data` so I could not found any way to `insert` bulk data using using `migrations.xml postgresql`